# Transforming collection using ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I want to do the following transformation using ramba

Input collection

```
const vals = [
        {metric: "Sales", measure:100, period_end_date: "2021-12-31", period_type: 'Annual' },
        {metric: "EBT", measure:101,  period_end_date: "2021-12-31", period_type: 'Annual' },
        {metric: "Sales", measure:100, period_end_date: "2021-09-30", period_type: 'Qtr' },
        {metric: "EBT", measure:101,  period_end_date: "2021-09-30", period_type: 'Qtr' }
       ]
```

Output

```
 {  
   "2021-09-30|Qtr": [{"Sales": 100}, {"EBT": 101],  
   "2021-12-31|Annual": [{"Sales": 100, }, {"EBT": 101,}] 
 }
```

I was able to come pretty close with this

```
const keyGen = compose(objOf('key'), join('|'),  props(['period_end_date','period_type']))// + '|' + prop("period_type",o) }

const valGen = compose(apply(objOf), R.ap([R.prop('metric'), R.prop('measure')]), of )

const f4 = map(compose(apply(merge), R.ap([keyGen, valGen]), of))

const result =compose(groupBy(prop('key')),f4 ) (vals)
```

This gives me the following result

```
{"2021-09-30|Qtr": [{"Sales": 100, "key": "2021-09-30|Qtr"}, 
                    {"EBT": 101, "key": "2021-09-30|Qtr"}], 
 "2021-12-31|Annual": [{"Sales": 100, "key": "2021-12-31|Annual"}, 
                       {"EBT": 101, "key": "2021-12-31|Annual"}]}
```

Now I need to remove the `key` from the inner collections. I wanted to know if there was a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`R.reduceBy`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduceBy) can be used to group items in a list and then reduce each group of items that have the same key.

```js
const vals = [
  {metric: "Sales", measure:100, period_end_date: "2021-12-31", period_type: 'Annual' },
  {metric: "EBT", measure:101,  period_end_date: "2021-12-31", period_type: 'Annual' },
  {metric: "Sales", measure:100, period_end_date: "2021-09-30", period_type: 'Qtr' },
  {metric: "EBT", measure:101,  period_end_date: "2021-09-30", period_type: 'Qtr' }
]

const fn = R.reduceBy(
  (list, {metric, measure}) => R.append({[metric]: measure}, list),
  [],
  ({period_end_date, period_type}) => `${period_end_date}|${period_type}`,
)

console.log(fn(vals))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should simplify your code and just use one simple function that reduces your collection to the desired output? I used `Array.prototype.reduce` which is easy translatable to Ramda's functional, point-free, curried style:

```
const convert = (acc, item) => {
  const name = `${item.period_end_date}|${item.period_type}`
  if (!acc[name]) acc[name] = []
  acc[name].push({ [item.metric]: item.measure })
  return acc
}

const transform = R.reduce(convert, {})
transform(vals)
```

And working snippet without Ramda:

```js
const vals = [{
    metric: "Sales",
    measure: 100,
    period_end_date: "2021-12-31",
    period_type: 'Annual'
  },
  {
    metric: "EBT",
    measure: 101,
    period_end_date: "2021-12-31",
    period_type: 'Annual'
  },
  {
    metric: "Sales",
    measure: 100,
    period_end_date: "2021-09-30",
    period_type: 'Qtr'
  },
  {
    metric: "EBT",
    measure: 101,
    period_end_date: "2021-09-30",
    period_type: 'Qtr'
  }
]

const result = vals.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const name = `${item.period_end_date}|${item.period_type}`
  if (!acc[name]) acc[name] = []
  acc[name].push({
    [item.metric]: item.measure
  })
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is something like this:

```js
const vals = [
  {metric: "Sales", measure:100, period_end_date: "2021-12-31", period_type: 'Annual' },
  {metric: "EBT", measure:101,  period_end_date: "2021-12-31", period_type: 'Annual' },
  {metric: "Sales", measure:100, period_end_date: "2021-09-30", period_type: 'Qtr' },
  {metric: "EBT", measure:101,  period_end_date: "2021-09-30", period_type: 'Qtr' }
]

const fn = R.pipe(
  R.groupBy(({period_end_date, period_type}) => `${period_end_date}|${period_type}`),
  R.map(R.map(R.lift(R.objOf)(R.prop('metric'), R.prop('measure'))))
);

console.log(fn(vals))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

The key point here is to `lift` `objOf` so that instead of working on *values*, it works on *containers of values*, in this case, functions that return them (`prop('metric')` and `prop('measure')`.)